# SQL Access for web apps

Tags: sql, web-applications, data-access-layer, data-access, three-tier

**Background**: 
Our team is building an inhouse Intranet web application.  We are using a standard three layer approach. Presentation layer (mvc web app), Business layer and data access layer.

Sql database is used for persistence.

Web app / iis handles user authentication (windows authentication). Logging is done in business and data access layer.

**Question service account vs user specific Sql accounts:**
*Use service / app account:*
Dev team is proposing to set up service account (set up for application only). This service account needs write & read access to db.

Vs

*Pass on user credentials to SQL*
IT ops is saying that using a service account (specifically created for app only) for db access is not deemed best practice. Set up Kerberos delegation configured from the web server to the SQL server so that you can pass on the Windows credentials of the end users & create a database role that grants the appropriate data access levels for end users

What is the best practice for setting up accounts in sql where all request to db will come through the front end client (ie via bus layer and then data layer)

Answer (score 2):

The Best Practice here is to let the person/team responsible for the database make the decision. It sounds like the dev team wants to forward (or impersonate) some credentials to the DB which I know that some small teams like doing, but yes that can leave things a bit too open. The app can do whatever it likes to the database, which is not much of a separation if you're into that kind of thing.

Personally, if I understand what you're saying above, I do more of what the IT team is thinking about (I use Postgres). In other words my app deploys over SSH using a given account (let's say it's the AppName account). That means I need to have my SSH keys lined up for secure deployment (using a PEM or known_keys or whatever).

In the home root for AppName I have [a file called .pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html) which has pretty specific security on it (0600). This means that my AppName account will use local security to get in rather than a username/password.

I do this because otherwise I'd need to store that information in a file somewhere - and those things get treated poorly [pushed to github, for instance](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DiscountASP&type=Code&ref=searchresults).

Ultimately, think 5 years from now and what your project and team will look like. Be optimistic - maybe it will be a smashing success! What will maintenance look like? What kinds of mistakes will your team make? Flexibility *now* is nice, but make sure that whomever will get in trouble if your database has a security problem is the one who gets to make the decision.

Comment: Thanks& agree - team responsible for db needs to make call. One question reg your answer. You mentioned you use appname account. So are any db calls made in appname account (&app account has full rights to db) or do u still pass on user credentials (through layers, if any)& make call in context of user?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to have individual accounts.  This allows you to use database facilities for identifying who is accessing the database.

This is particularly important if the data is being modified.  You can log who is modifying what data -- generally a hard-core requirement in any system where users have this ability.

You may find that, for some reason, you do not want to use your database's built-in authentication mechanisms.  In that case, you are probably going to build a layer on top of the database, replicating much of the built-in functionality.  There are situations where this might be necessary.  In general, this would be a dangerous approach (the database security mechanisms probably undergo much more testing than bespoke code).

Finally, if you are building an in-house application with just a handful of users who have read-only access to the database, it might be simpler to have only a single login account.  Normally, you would still like to know who is doing what, but for simplicity, you might forego that functionality.  However, knowing who is doing what is usually very useful knowledge for maintaining and enhancing the application.

Comment: I'll add that the app does authentication/auditing/logging (ie happens at business layer and or data access layer). Thus there is no use of using sql authentication & logging that I can see

Comment: I would also like to highlight that users cannot make calls direct to db. They always go through the client.

Comment: @MarkH . . . It is a rare application that would not benefit from knowing who is using which features for maintenance and development work.